# mysql replication through workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have mysql replication between 2 servers, and the slave is usually updated.

But when I manually change fields in the master sql server from the workbench, suddenly the slave is not updated.

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: you see any errors? what do you get when you execute: show slave status\G?

Answer (score 2):

replication is only done if the default schema is for a database that is being replicated. for example, if you have replication set up for db1, but not db2, executing the following:

```
mysql db2 -e 'update db1.mytable set myfield=1;'
```

the update will not be replicated. i believe it is possible to execute such commands from mysql workbench without selecting a default schema, which may cause the command to not be replicated.